# get responce from another server in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my mvc application i need to responce or return view value from another server.

Like calling from one MVC application in a server to another mvc application in a server.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the response from a server using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) and return it as text:

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        string response = client.DownloadString("http://otherserver/controller/action");
        return Content(response, "text/html");
    }
}
```